# how to update sites in the siteadmin programmatically

Tags: aem, crx

Which javascript function is responsible for refrishing the sites in site admin see screenshot?

I would like to use it to update the sites after I have changed some page properties programmatically. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the `reloadPages` function defined in `SiteAdmin.js` present in your libs.

Comment: and how to get siteAdmin object ? I tried CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.reloadPages(); but this causes error (CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.reloadPages() is not a function)